# get package.json from GitLab npm package

Tags: npm, gitlab

is it possible to get the `package.json` from a GitLab npm package? With the GitLab API I can call up the GitLap package information. But I haven't found any way to read the `package.json` without load the full package. Especially I need the tags from the `package.json`.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: thank you for correcting my post.
No, I can't show a code yet. I'm still looking for functions that I can use to achieve my goal. At the moment I have focused on the GitLab API. I get the GitLab package information via `https://{{SERVER}}/api/v4/groups/{{GROUP}}/packages?exclude_subgroups=true&package_type=npm`. The information that I get back does not contain the NPM information from `Package.json`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the `package.json` information of a certain package from an npm registry? I would like to determine the data without downloading the full package.